# Filter data out from text file using php

Tags: php, text-files

**This is what I have basically:**

```
$data = file('../articles.txt');

$data=str_replace(array('<', '>', '\\', '/', '='), "", $data);

foreach($data as $element) 

{
$element = trim($element);
$pieces = explode("|", $element);

echo "

<div class=article-box>

<div class=article-image>
<a href=" . $pieces[4] . "/" . $pieces[2] . "/ ><img src=" . $pieces[4] . "/" . $pieces[2] . "/" . $pieces[2] . "-img.png width=250px></a>  
</div>
```

The code doesn't end here, but I hope that makes sense so far.

What I need is to only echo those lines that have a certain value of `$pieces[4]` for example. Let's say - echo only those lines in a text file that have `$pieces[4]` value "food".

Is it possible somehow? I tried array search, array keys, filtered array etc ... but I never got it right.

**UPDATE: 
Pedro's answer (half way there):**

```
{
$element = trim($element);
if (strpos($element,'food') !== false) {
$pieces = explode("|", $element);    
}
```

Kind of works - it does the job, but replaces those outputs that I want to hide with those that are filtered out.

What I want is to skip outputs that do not contain given value. At the moment it skips the unneeded outputs but replaces those with blank values or just multiplies filtered outputs. Below is an explanation about what lines are needed to echo and what lines to skip.

```
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|food|comment|extra - needs to trigger echo
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|health|comment|extra - needs to skip
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|food|comment|extra - needs to trigger echo
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|finance|comment|extra - needs to skip
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|finance|comment|extra - needs to skip
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|health|comment|extra - needs to skip
2015-10-05|21:31|name1|name2|food|comment|extra - needs to trigger echo
```

What the code above does right now is:

1. correct output
2. output replaced (same as output 1) - needs to be skipped
3. correct output
4. output replaced (same as output 3) - needs to be skipped
5. output replaced (same as output 3) - needs to be skipped
6. output replaced (same as output 3) - needs to be skipped
7. correct output

So, it manages to filter out what I need, but those that don't match the criteria are just replaced by the last matched line. But I need those to be skipped instead.

**The only thing that is missing is to complement Pedro's answer above so that the lines (that do not meet criteria `$pieces[4]`="food") 2,4,5,6 are skipped, ignored and not echoed at all.**

Comment: use `$data=str_replace(array('<', '>', '\\', '/', '='), "", $data);` inside `foreach`(change `$data` to `$element`), so that you could filter vals out, also, it would be great if you post some of your text file contents

Comment: Pedro's answer works, but then it multiplies the result with a total number of lines in a document. Now i just need to figure out how to stop that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to check if the line contains the word `food`

```
$element = trim($element);
if (strpos($element,'food') !== false) {
    $pieces = explode("|", $element);
    //the rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It works, but ... it filters the needed lines and then multiplies it with the number of lines in total. Lets say i have 2 lines that contain pieces named "food". At first it echoes those 2 lines and then repeats the last line as much as there is total lines in a document.

Comment: Pedro, can you please help me to solve the issue with the multiply issue. How can I limit the outcome to echo just once?

Comment: Can you please post a small sample of the input file and the desired output? If so, please update your question.

Comment: I updated the main question. Thank you for taking your time. This has been much help so far.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you...Nothing is replaced on my answer, it's simply filtered. You may want to post a real example.

Comment: Im new here. Sorry :)

Comment: I made an update. Can you please check the updated question once more? I need those lines that do not have keyword "food" in them to be skipped and ignored while generating the output. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I got it right now. I added an answer to show the result.

Answer (score 0):

I did some adjustment to Pedro's answer and I think I got the result I needed. Code is like that:

```
<?php
$data = file('../articles.txt');

$data=str_replace(array('<', '>', '\\', '/', '='), "", $data);
foreach($data as $element) 
{
$element = trim($element);
if (strpos($element,'food') !== false) {
$pieces = explode("|", $element);
echo "
```

Some HTML and PHP here that does not need any adjustments.

```
";    
}
else {
echo "";
}
}
?>
```

At first I added echo "error"; to the else part but it was just for testing. I got the disturbing error message to dissapear simply by deleting it. At the moment it seems like it is working just like that.

If I don't add the else part then I'm back at the problem where it filters out the lines that have value "food" in it but also echoes everything else only this time with zero values.